# What causes coldfusion.document.spi.DocumentExportException: java.lang.NullPointerException issue?

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, nullpointerexception, cfdocument

This exception is being thrown by my ColdFusion application whenever I try to generate pdf reports using cfdocument.

Problem is, till 5 days ago everything was working perfectly and I was getting the reports. The suddenly, since yesterday morning, I have been getting the above error.

I have researched about this on the net extensively and have confirmed that:
1. Error is not occurring due to use of unknown fonts.
2. Missing CFM files.

Can somebody tell me if there is any other reason for this exception to occur suddenly.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you running?  I've seen some issues with CF9 where it would suddenly start throwing errors for CFDocument.  But a service restart would bring it back to working order.

Comment: I have restarted the service multiple times and restarted the server as well but it's not going away. Can it be a DB issue?

Comment: Any chance you can show us the Java stack trace from the logs?  Also, have you tried scoping query variables? http://blog.dkferguson.com/index.cfm/2008/1/11/CFDocument--pdf-generation-broke-after-CF8-upgrade

Comment: I suspect you have a  file I/O problem or corrupt template cache. It's a wild guess :)   Try deleting your template cache, defragging your disk etc.  See if you can tune up file i/o.

Comment: @MisterDai Here you go.....http://www.filedropper.com/500-internalservererror

Comment: Update on this....@MarkAKruger....cleared template and query cache but it didn't help. I think this issue needs to be addressed immediately. Writing a mail to Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue a few months back with one of my servers and has to re-install Coldfusion enterprise server. This is probably not the correct solution but can be used as a last resort.

Comment: I considered that option but there are 140+ applications on this server with users in different time zones around the world. Hence, that's something I am not willing to do. Also, what if this issue reoccurs? Looking for a permanent solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Unknown if this is still an issue with CF9, but CF8 had problems with unscoped query variables inside the CFDocumentItem tag.

http://blog.dkferguson.com/index.cfm/2008/1/11/CFDocument--pdf-generation-broke-after-CF8-upgrade

Comment: I have read been to this blog before. Issue is that this application has been working fine for some quiet time now and then suddenly this. Also, the query variables are first set (<cfset varname="#queryname.co#lumnname">) and then used in the application(basically the same page with cfinclude for multiple files).

Comment: MAJOR ISSUE: A while back I reported this issue to Adobe also and they asked for more details. Upon providing details on how to reproduce this error on my server, the were so baffled that today they sent a team down to my office for further research on this. Finally, they admit that this is a rare case and might be a product defect! They have taken this up on priority and promised to find it's cause ASAP. I'll keep you guys posted on further developments!